# PHP Deprecated: header(): php 8.014

Tags: php, php-8

When I click on log Off in my admin, this error aooears in my log.
I do not understand what is deprecated php 8.0.14
thank you for your help

my function

```
 public static function redirect(?string $url, ?string $http_response_code = null)
    {
      if ((strstr($url, "\n") === false) && (strstr($url, "\r") === false)) {
        if (str_contains($url, '&amp;')) {
          $url = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $url);
        }

        header('Location: ' . $url, true, $http_response_code);
      }

      exit;
    }
```

the error

```
[25-Dec-2021 15:32:00 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  header(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($response_code) of type int is deprecated in /home/www/test/includes/OM/HTTP.php on line 63
[25-Dec-2021 15:32:00 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[25-Dec-2021 15:32:00 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /home/www/test/admin/login.php:0
[25-Dec-2021 15:32:00 UTC] PHP   2. OM\OM::redirect() /home/www/test/admin/test.php:133
[25-Dec-2021 15:32:00 UTC] PHP   3. OM\HTTP::redirect($url = 'http://localhost/test/admin/index.php', $http_response_code = *uninitialized*) /home/www/test/includes/OM/::OM.php:329
[25-Dec-2021 15:32:00 UTC] PHP   4. header($header = 'Location: http://localhost/test/admin/index.php', $replace = TRUE, $response_code = NULL) /home/www/test/includes/OM/HTTP.php:63
[25-Dec-2021 15:32:12 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  header(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($response_code) of type int is deprecated in /home/www/test/includes/admin/OM/HTTP.php on line 63
[25-Dec-2021 15:32:12 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[25-Dec-2021 15:32:12 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /home/www/test/admin/login.php:0
[25-Dec-2021 15:32:12 UTC] PHP   2. OM\OM::redirect('index.php', '') /home/www/test/admin/login.php:100
[25-Dec-2021 15:32:12 UTC] PHP   3. OM\HTTP::redirect($url = 'http://localhost/admin/admin/index.php', $http_response_code = *uninitialized*) /home/www/test/includes/OM/OM.php:329
[25-Dec-2021 15:32:12 UTC] PHP   4. header($header = 'Location: http://localhost/test/admin/index.php', $replace = TRUE, $response_code = NULL) /home/www/test/includes/OM/HTTP.php:63
```

Comment: What's deprecated is the act of passing `null` as the response code parameter - exactly as the error message says

Answer (score 4):

```
public static function redirect(?string $url, ?string $http_response_code = null)
```

must be

```
public static function redirect(?string $url, int $http_response_code = 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace by this code:

```php
public static function redirect(?string $url, ?string $http_response_code = null)
{
    if ((strstr($url, "\n") === false) && (strstr($url, "\r") === false)) {
        if (str_contains($url, '&amp;')) {
            $url = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $url);
        }

        if ($http_response_code === null) {
            header('Location: ' . $url);
        } else {
            header('Location: ' . $url, true, $http_response_code);
        }
    }

    exit;
}
```

The third argument of the `header` function must not be of type `null`, hence the deprecated message.

Comment: Your 3rd argument on function `redirect()` still accept string. [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) accept `response_code` argument as integer only. Your condition `if ($http_response_code === null)` means if developer enter the 3rd argument as `'blabla'` then it will be send as `header('Location: url', true, 'blabla');` and the error still occur.

It is better to change type hint and check variable type in `if` condition.

Comment: @vee, I completely agree. In the answer, I preferred to keep the original method signature. IMHO this is already beyond the scope of this question.